# Getting errors in porting a Chisel test to sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, chisel

I have a working peek-poke tester, tested in jupyter notebook.
I am porting it to sbt, I have tried syntax from two books and one from my professor, but none has worked so far.

The project directory structure is based on the template -
https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template

The working base tester that I need to port to sbt is -

```
def test_sync_fifo: Boolean = {
    test(new sync_fifo(64, 32)) { c =>
         // .... Pokes and peeks
    }
    println(getVerilog(new sync_fifo(64, 32)))
    true
}

assert(test_sync_fifo)
```

What I have already tried are -

```
import chisel3 ._
import chisel3 . iotesters ._ // Gives error - iotesters not found

class TesterSimple (dut: sync_fifo(64, 32) ) extends
    PeekPokeTester (dut) {        // Gives error = PeekPokeTester not found
    // .. Peeks and pokes
}

object TesterSimple extends App {
    chisel3 . iotesters . Driver (() => new sync_fifo(64, 32)) { c =>
    new TesterSimple (c) 
    }
}
```

I also tried -

```
//In build.sbt - I expect this to be wrong
lazy val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies ++= scalatest


import org. scalatest ._
class SimpleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
" Test " should "pass" in {
    chisel3 . iotesters . Driver (() => new sync_fifo(64, 32)) { c =>
        new Tester (c)
        } should be (true)
    }
}
```

I also tried -

```
import Chisel._

class test_sync_fifo (c: sync_fifo(64, 32))
extends Tester(c) {
    // Peeks and pokes
}
```

Any pointers will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Your examples look pretty good. What error messages are you receiving

Comment: HI @ChickMarkley. Thanks. Case 1 - ```[error] test_funnel_shifter.scala:7:16: object iotesters is not a member of package chisel3
 import chisel3.iotesters._                ^
[error] test_funnel_shifter.scala:13:5: not found: type PeekPokeTester
     PeekPokeTester (c) {  
[error] test_funnel_shifter.scala:13:21: no arguments allowed for nullary constructor Object: ()Object
   PeekPokeTester (c) {  
         
[error] test_funnel_shifter.scala:169:13: object iotesters is not a member of package chisel3
[    chisel3.iotesters.Driver(() => new funnel_shifter(4, 21, 9, 42) ) { c =>```

Comment: I got the case 2 to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see your full `SBT` file, but I'm pretty sure you're missing a dependency on `iotesters`. Assuming you're using chisel3 version `3.4.x` or newer, you should add the following to your `build.sbt`:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel-iotesters" % "1.5.3"
```

And see this docs page for information about which versions of the various projects work together: https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/appendix/versioning.html